# ArcGIS runtime SDK 10.1.1 for java does not display anything

Tags: display, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I am currently trying to display a map (using OpenStreetMapLayer) and nothing shows up but the esri logo and the OpenStreetMap copyright. I am not getting any error message even if the event mapReady never occurs.

I am running the application on a distant server (via Remote Desktop) on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (SP1) and using the jre 1.7.0_25 x86. Although the SDK version is 10.1.1, an ArcGIS 10.2 application is installed on the server (ArcMap and others).

Another strange thing is that even the SDK samples seem to encounter the same issue when run in the same conditions (I cannot try on another PC). See the screenshot below:
[image: SDK sample displaying nothing]

I have been searching the web for two days but found nothing and, as there are no error messages, I ran out of ideas to google.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the samples are using web map services from ArcGIS Online, but like in my case, we have company security issues, so it's much more a proxy issue, than ArcGIS.

For instance, if you try the sample Mapping > Tiled Layers > Tiled Layer, it should work.

But if all your sample with (online) are not showing map, it's because of firewall or proxy restriction/configuration.